# I don't want to continuously backup on Google's Backup and Sync

Tags: backup, sync, google-drive

Well, I always used the Google Drive app on my older computer, it only backed up files on the "Google Drive" folder and the ones I told it to. 
Now, there's this new app "Backup and Sync" and it seems impossible to just use it without continuously backing up my computer.

The two options on the Preferences are:
Backup EVERYTHING
or
Backup just photos and videos

I couldn't find an option to disable the backup, so I can't use Google Drive like I used before, just to save some files of my choice.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what they mean by *everything*
When you open *preferences* you start in the *Home* tab. This is where you choose which folders to backup. When you then choose backup *EVERYTHING* it meeans **everything in those specific folders**. If you choose *Backup photos and videos* they mean only photos and videos in those folders
If you want to sync the *drive* folder you go to the *Google Drive* tab and check the *Sync My Drive to this computer* checkbox.

Comment: I was worried because no matter what I selected, it would say "preparing 2000 files" and start to raise, until near 100k files.

So i thought it would back up a lot of things, but I waited some time and it finished "preparing" those files, then, backed up only what I needed.

Don't know what it was doing, but now it's working. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked out for you! No probs